# Add ASP.NET CORE Identity to existing multi-project solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-migrations

I am adding the ASP.NET CORE Identity to an existing Model project in my solution.  The Model project contains only the DbContext and POCO classes that were created by EF CORE POWER TOOLS. The tables that are mapped by the entity classes contain data that need to be retained.  I successfully created the migration script, but the script also includes the tables in the existing database. When applied the Update-Migration, it complained that the tables exist and error out. What am I doing wrong?  Should I manually delete the portion of the script that will recreate existing tables?  Is there a way to do the migration without touching existing tables that have data?

Comment: In DbContext you can comment unnecessarily tables and then try to migrate it hopefully it waill works

Comment: I commented out all the DbSet<T> statements and OnModelCreating(), so the DbContext class has only the skeleton.  The migration would not build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I can migrate now after removing the unnecessary statement in the Up() and Down() methods.  If there are multiple projects in the solution, the project that would not be compiled successfully can be unloaded, so that EF Migration would be able to compile the solution to migrate.